# How to find word frequencies of each word from a large corpus?

Tags: php, python, counting, cpu-word, corpus

*I have asked this question about a month ago. However, no one gave an answer or even comment.I am repeating the question so that someone would help this time.*

I have a large Unicode Monolingual corpus consists over 100 million words in a txt file of size 1.7GB. Now I need to find the word frequency of each word in that corpus so that I can find 20 most frequent words and 20 Least frequent words in the corpus. Such as,(the example is given in Swedish instead of Bengali for easy understanding)

**Corpus:**

> jag har ett stort hus också jag har ett stort fält jag.

**Word Frequency:**

> jag 3
>
> har 2
>
> ett 2
>
> stort 2
>
> hus 1
>
> fält  1

**Desicion:**

> most frequent:
>
> jag 3
>
> har 2
>
> Least frequent:
>
> hus 1
>
> fält  1

**BUT,** when I have tried to use a mysql database to store new words from corpus and increase its freqeuncy each time by one. so that finally I can get the words with their frequency. however, it took 2 days to complete even 10% of the corpus. I have tried another way by keeping a txt file to keep a record about the frequency of each word. However it fails due to the system doesn't work for unicode words. Please suggest me a easy and fast way to count to this ( Can be in PHP or PYTHON).

Answer (score 1):

In python, the simplest way is to use [collections.Counter](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter) to create a counter object. I timed it out using a (very limited) 200,000 word corpus

```
from collections import Counter

x='jag har ett stort hus också jag har ett stort fält jag cat rat bat cat bar baz cat jag '

x=x*10000

%timeit c=Counter(x.split())

49.4 ms ± 7.51 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)

c.most_common(5)
[('jag', 40000),
 ('cat', 30000),
 ('har', 20000),
 ('ett', 20000),
 ('stort', 20000)]
```

That being said, >100 million words is just going to be a very very large task, and I would expect to run into memory and time issues. I would expect that you would have better luck operating on partial chunks of your data at a time.

You may also look into multiprocessing